# Why actual mapping is called as unreferenced mapping in this context of residual framework?

Tags: terminology, papers, residual-networks

Consider the following statements from the research paper titled [Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/He_Deep_Residual_Learning_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf) by *Kaiming He et al*.

#1:

> We explicitly reformulate the layers as learning residual functions
> with reference to the layer inputs, instead of learning **unreferenced
> functions**. We provide comprehensive empirical evidence showing that
> these residual networks are easier to optimize, and can gain accuracy
> from considerably increased depth.

#2:

> In this paper, we address the degradation problem by introducing a
> deep residual learning framework. Instead of hoping each few stacked
> layers directly fit a desired underlying mapping, we explicitly let
> these layers fit a residual mapping. Formally, denoting the desired
> underlying mapping as $\mathcal{H}(x)$, we let the stacked nonlinear
> layers fit another mapping of $\mathcal{F}(x) := \mathcal{H}(x)−x$.
> The original mapping is recast into $\mathcal{F}(x)+x$. We hypothesize
> that it is easier to optimize the residual mapping than to optimize
> the original, **unreferenced mapping**. To the extreme, if an identity
> mapping were optimal, it would be easier to push the residual to zero
> than to fit an identity mapping by a stack of nonlinear layers.

The research paper contains the word "unreferenced" twice for a function, which I think is the actual function $\mathcal{H}(x)$. In normal deep neural networks, the function $\mathcal{H}(x)$ is generally learned. But, $\mathcal{F}(x)$ is learned in the residual neural networks and hence $\mathcal{H}(x)$.

Why this paper is calling the original function $\mathcal{H}(x)$as **unreferenced** function?